# awk slab calculation based on range

Tags: awk

Would like to calculate slab calculation based on StartRange, EndRange, Category and Flag_value information.

SampleInput.txt

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6
Desc,Name,Category,Desc2,Flag_Value,Slab_Count
ZZZ,ABC,A,xyz,2,140
ZZZ,CDE,A,xyz,-5,140
ZZZ,FGH,B,xyz,10,48
ZZZ,IJK,B,xyz,-10,48
ZZZ,LMN,C,xyz,115,248
ZZZ,OPQ,A,ijk,-62,250
ZZZ,RST,D,ijk,67,350
ZZZ,UVW,A,ijk,-80,5
ZZZ,XYZ,A,ijk,48,6
```

Slab.txt

```
StartRange,EndRange,Category-A,Category-B,Category-C,Category-D,Flag_Value
1,50,350,350,500,500,-125
51,100,450,500,550,600,-150
101,150,600,600,600,650,-150
151,200,700,650,650,650,-200
201,250,800,750,700,700,-250
251,1000,900,850,800,800,-300
```

Method to calculate First line of SampleInput.txt, need to take the input from  SampleInput.txt Field3 (i.e A) , Field5>0 (i.e 2)  and Field6 (i.e 140)
then lookup data from Slab.txt to find the lying range (i.e 101,150,600,600,600,650,-150) , category (i.e Category-A) and print corresponding value i.e 600

Second line of SampleInput.txt, need to take the input from  SampleInput.txt Field3 (i.e A) , Field5<0 (i.e -5)  and Field6 (i.e 140) then lookup data from Slab.txt
to find the lying range (i.e 101,150,600,600,600,650,-150) , category (i.e Category-A) and print corresponding value of addition Category-A+Flag_Value i.e 450 (600-150)

Expected Output.txt

```
Desc,Name,Category,Desc2,Flag_Value,Slab_Count,Slab_Amt
ZZZ,ABC,A,xyz,2,140,600
ZZZ,CDE,A,xyz,-5,140,450
ZZZ,FGH,B,xyz,10,48,350
ZZZ,IJK,B,xyz,-10,48,225
ZZZ,LMN,C,xyz,115,248,700
ZZZ,OPQ,A,ijk,-62,250,550
ZZZ,RST,D,ijk,67,350,800
ZZZ,UVW,A,ijk,-80,5,225
ZZZ,XYZ,A,ijk,48,6,350
```

searched lot in the google to find relevant attempts and failed to find the same , stucked to find at complex level, looking for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another possibility:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } 
NR == 1 { next } 
FNR == 1 { print $0, "Slab_Amt" }
NR == FNR { 
    range[$1,$2,"A"] = $3
    range[$1,$2,"B"] = $4
    range[$1,$2,"C"] = $5
    range[$1,$2,"D"] = $6
    flag[$1,$2] = $NF
    next
}   
{
    for (key in range) {
        split (key, tmp, SUBSEP);
        if (tmp[3] == $3 && tmp[1] <= $NF && $NF <= tmp[2]) {
            value = ( $5 > 0 ? range[key] : range[key] + flag[tmp[1],tmp[2]] )
            print $0, value
            next
        }
    }
}' Slab.txt SampleInput.txt
```

#### Output:

```
Desc,Name,Category,Desc2,Flag_Value,Slab_Count,Slab_Amt
ZZZ,ABC,A,xyz,2,140,600
ZZZ,CDE,A,xyz,-5,140,450
ZZZ,FGH,B,xyz,10,48,350
ZZZ,IJK,B,xyz,-10,48,225
ZZZ,LMN,C,xyz,115,248,700
ZZZ,OPQ,A,ijk,-62,250,550
ZZZ,RST,D,ijk,67,350,800
ZZZ,UVW,A,ijk,-80,5,225
ZZZ,XYZ,A,ijk,48,6,350
```

#### Explanation:

- We set the Input and Output Field Separators to `,` using `BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }`
- If it is first line of first file we skip it using `NR == 1 { next }`
- For the first line of our second file we print adding the `Slab_Amt` as header using `FNR == 1 { print $0, "Slab_Amt" }`
- We iterate through the `Slab.txt` file storing the values of each category in our multi-dimensional array having Start Range, End Range and Category as Keys in `range` array.
- We store the flag value in `flag` array keyed at the Start and End ranges.
- When we start to process the `SampleInput.txt` file, we iterate our range array and split the key.
- We check if third piece of our key is equal to 3rd column of Sample Input and Last Column is in between our ranges. If it is we calculate the value by checking if the 5th column is greater than 0. If it is we just assign the value of our range if not we add the range value to flag value and print the line along with our value.
- Using `next` we skip further checks and move to the next line of Sample Input.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaypal, it is working fine, could you please provide some explanation to understand the code

Comment: @AVN Have added an explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AVN In addition to jaypal's explanation, you need to read the [gnu awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) (or some other manual/book) to learn the language.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility.

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN {
  getline <"Slab.txt"  # skip header
  while ((getline <"Slab.txt") > 0)
    slabs[int($2)] = $0
  # Last index must be greater than top of range
  slabs[999999] = "endmarker"
}
NR == 2 { print $0",Slab_Amt" }
NR > 2 {
  n = int($6)
  for (rangetop in slabs)
    if (n <= int(rangetop))
      break
  if (rangetop == 999999) {
    print "n out of range:",n >"/dev/stderr"
    exit(1)
  }
  split(slabs[rangetop], fields, ",")
  switch ($3) {
  case "A":  val = fields[3]; break
  case "B":  val = fields[4]; break
  case "C":  val = fields[5]; break
  case "D":  val = fields[6]; break
  default:
    print "unknown category:",$3 >"/dev/stderr"
    exit(1)
  }
  if ($5 < 0)
     val += fields[7]
  print $0","val
}
' SampleInput.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ ooga for your inputs but it seems incorrect output ,Desc,Name,Category,Desc2,Flag_Value,Slab_Count,
ZZZ,ABC,A,xyz,2,140,800
ZZZ,CDE,A,xyz,-5,140,550

Comment: expected output Desc,Name,Category,Desc2,Flag_Value,Slab_Count,Slab_Amt
ZZZ,ABC,A,xyz,2,140,600
ZZZ,CDE,A,xyz,-5,140,450

Comment: That's probably because I was assuming the headings weren't actually in the data files. I'll edit it, but I prefer jaypal's answer anyway.